# How to left align Mathjax elements

Tags: mathjax

Mathjax elements are by default, center aligned.

How can I make Mathjax elements left aligned?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

```
MathJax.Hub.Config({
    jax: ["input/TeX","output/HTML-CSS"],
    displayAlign: "left"
});
```

Comment: This is the better solution. Important has too high a precedence and should be avoided.

Comment: Also, if you've come here, it is likely that you want to set a left padding: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12707094/how-to-change-padding-of-math-in-mathjax?lq=1

Comment: I came here looking how to set centering for only one expression.

Answer (score 12):

I find a trick only in MathJax semantic by add *\hspace{10cm} at the first line end*[[MathJax and left align](https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/%7Epkates/MathJax/left-align.html)].code like this:

```
$$
\begin{align}
x & = 1+1 \hspace{100cm} \\
& = 2
\end{align}
$$
```

For example my code is:

```
$$
\begin{aligned}
\sqrt{37} & = \sqrt{\frac{73^2-1}{12^2}} \\
 & = \sqrt{\frac{73^2}{12^2}\cdot\frac{73^2-1}{73^2}} \\ 
 & = \sqrt{\frac{73^2}{12^2}}\sqrt{\frac{73^2-1}{73^2}} \\
 & = \frac{73}{12}\sqrt{1 - \frac{1}{73^2}} \\ 
 & \approx \frac{73}{12}\left(1 - \frac{1}{2\cdot73^2}\right)
\end{aligned}
$$
```

And the Effect like this:

[image: align]

Answer (score 10):

Or my solution with CSS:

```
.MathJax_Display {
  text-align: left !important;
}
```

It worked for me.

Comment: This appears to be broken at the moment.

Comment: Doesn't work anymore in case anyone comes across this.

Answer (score 6):

[According to the MathJax 3.0 documentation](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/v3.0-latest/options/output/index.html#options-common-to-all-output-processors) you need the `displayAlign` option by adding the following to your HTML file:

```
<script>
    MathJax = {
        chtml: { displayAlign: 'left' }
    };
</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

Edit to previous answer, this works perfectly for me

```
.MathJax_Display { 
    text-align: left !important;
    display: inline !important;
}
```

Comment: That is invalid CSS. What is the `<br>` doing there?

Answer (score 3):

The other answers didn't work for me - but what did work was modifying the MathML that MathJax was displaying (and I know there are equivalents for other input formats).  I was trying to indent right, but the concept is the same.

For MathML I had to add `indentalign="right"` to the `<math ...>` tag, eg:

`<math indentalign="right" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">...</math>`

after which MathJax correctly right-aligned my content.

Answer (score 2):

In the current version of MathJax (2.7.5) with the standard configuration TeX-MML-AM_CHTML, the text-align property is set on an element with classes mjx-chtml and MJXc-display. Therefore the solutions building on MathJax_Display  won't work anymore.

For more flexibility you can add a parent `<div class="math-left-align">` to your math content, such that you can choose how to align your math case-by-case.

Your HTML would then look like

```
<div class="math-left-align">
    $$ a + b = c $$
</div>
```

And the corresponding CSS

```
.math-left-align .mjx-chtml.MJXc-display{
    text-align: left !important;
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

@上山老人's answer works beautifully for me. To clarify,

- Instead of `&=&`, use `& =` for every `=` within a block between `\begin{align}` and `\end{align}`.

In my environment (using Typora),

- `\begin{align}` adds (1), (2), ... to every line. Verbose.
- `\begin{align*}` without such numbers
- `\begin{aligned}` adds just one (1) for multiple lines

```latex
\begin{aligned}
\cos 3\theta & = \cos (2 \theta + \theta) \\
& = \cos 2 \theta \cos \theta - \sin 2 \theta \sin \theta \\
& = (2 \cos ^2 \theta -1) \cos \theta - (2 \sin \theta\cos \theta ) \sin \theta \\
& = 2 \cos ^3 \theta - \cos \theta - 2 \sin ^2 \theta \cos \theta \\
& = 2 \cos ^3 \theta - \cos \theta - 2 (1 - \cos ^2 \theta )\cos \theta \\
& = 4 \cos ^3 \theta -3 \cos \theta 
\end{aligned}
```

[image: rendering sample]

Another way is to use `\eqalign{...}`

```latex
$$
\eqalign{s^2 &= \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n{(a_k - \bar{a})^2} \\
&= \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n{(a_k^2 -2\cdot a_k\cdot\bar{a} + \bar{a}^2)} \\
  &= \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n{a_k^2} -\frac{2\cdot\bar{a}}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n{(a_k) + \bar{a}^2} \\
 &= \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n{a_k^2} - \bar{a}^2 \\
 &= \bar{a^2} - \bar{a}^2 \\}
$$
```

[image: eqalign_example]

Answer (score 1):

I have found that one can left align MathJax equations by wrapping them in a 0 width left-aligned `div`

For example, whereas this give a "centered" equation in the middle of the document:

```
<body>
$$ f(x) = x^2 $$
</body>
```

This would give a left-aligned equation:

```
<body>
    <div style="width:0; float:left;">
        $$ f(x) = x^2 $$
    </div>
</body>
```

[jsbin](https://jsbin.com/jocabujado/1/edit?html,output)

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be working for MathJax 3.0,

```js
MathJax = {
  tex: {
    inlineMath: [
      ['$', '$'],
      ['\\(', '\\)']
    ]
  }
};
```

```css
.left {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.right {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

```html
  <script id="MathJax-script" async src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-chtml.js">
  </script>


<div class="left">
  $$\text{ex1: } \frac{1}{2}
</div>

<br>

<div class="right">
  $$\text{ex2: } \frac{12}{6}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

As of 2021 I had to use

```
mjx-container {
    text-align: left !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Following code works for me.

```
<script>
MathJax = {
  tex: {
    inlineMath: [['$', '$'], ['\\(', '\\)']],
    tags: 'ams'
  },
  svg: {
    fontCache: 'global',
    displayAlign: 'left',
    displayIndent: '1.5em'
  }
};
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" id="MathJax-script" async
  src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-svg.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

you could use $\phantom{=}$ to introduce an in invisible equality sign to align at:

$$\begin{align}&\phantom{=}\lbrace \left(x_i,y_i\right),\   x_i\in\mathbb{X}, y_i\in \mathbb{R}\rbrace_{i=1}^n\\
&\phantom{=}f: (x\in\mathbb{X},,p_1,\dots,, p_k\in\mathbb{R})\mapsto y\in\mathbb{R}\\
&\phantom{=}0\le q\le n\end{align}$$

you may of course use any other character instead of '='