# How to change padding of math in MathJax?

Tags: jquery, html, css, mathjax

Like, when I have my piece of Math in my div, it would look like this, where I have set the padding of my div to `0`:

[image: Even when I set the padding of my wrapper div to zero.]

So, is there a way to change the value of the padding of the math?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11296415/how-to-left-align-mathjax-elements) (and to believe I answered this question, and forgot about it):

```
MathJax.Hub.Config({
    jax: ["input/TeX","output/HTML-CSS"],
    displayIndent: "2em"
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to customize this would be call `MathJax.Hub.Config(...)` before you load the MathJax config file in your header.  For example:

```
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
MathJax.Hub.Config({
    "HTML-CSS": {
        styles: {
            ".MathJax nobr": {
                padding: "0.2em 0.2em"
            },
        }
    }
});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_HTML" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Where you change the path to your MathJax installation.

Alternatively, you can either modify an existing config file or setup your own config via the method outlined here: http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/configuration.html#config-files